# Set HTTP status code for inbound gateway reply timeout?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm creating a web service that is a gateway to another web service. I'm using the Spring Integration framework, specifically an `Http Inbound Gateway` to accept incoming requests. When the `reply-timeout` is triggered, a 200 status code is returned. Ideally I'd like to return a 504 since my web service has not received a timely reply from the other web service I'm communicating with.

```
 <int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="authorizationRequestsChannel"
                      reply-channel="myReplyChannel"
                      path="/endpoint"
                      reply-timeout="30000"
                      supported-methods="POST" />
```

**tl;dr**

When the reply channel times-out, the `inbound-gateway` returns a 200 status code. Is it possible to set the status code to another value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

However, you can add an error channel; and set a timeout on your downstream component. The error flow will be invoked when the flow throws an exception and the error flow can return a message with a status code header.

We'll take a look at adding a mechanism to customize the status code for a timeout.

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3781).